# Using array.filter() to return objects that have a value containing keywords

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working with node.js and have an array called `products` that is structured like the following:

`[ {  product_id: 'adidas-training-shoes',
      title: 'Adidas Training Shoes',
      description: 'description',
      brand: 'brand',
      variants: [ [Object], [Object] ],
      thumbnail_url: 'url' },
   {  product_id: 'nike-running-shoes',
      title: 'Nike Running Shoes',
      description: 'description',
      brand: 'brand',
      variants: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
      thumbnail_url: 'url' },
   {  product_id: 'vans-sneakers',
      title: 'Vans Sneakers',
      description: 'description',
      brand: 'brand',
      variants: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
      thumbnail_url: 'url' } ]`

I also have a config.json file which contains my keyword list (among other things) like so:

`{
   "keywords": [
    "vans",
    "nike" ]
 }`

I want to use `products.filter()` to filter this array and return the objects (products) whose `product.title` contains any of my keywords in `config.keywords`.

I'm very much a beginner with javascript and I'm working with ES6 so it's a bit confusing for me.  If it would be easier to use a different version of js other than ES6 I'd be glad to switch over.  Also, I've spent quite researching before asking this question and hope it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const filteredProducts = products.filter((product) => (
  config.keywords.some((keyword) => (
    product.title.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase())
  ))
));
```

> If at least one of the config keywords (some) is found to be in the product title (includes) return true.

You can ditch the `.toLowerCase()`s if it doesn't need to be case-insensitive.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! If I'm going through roughly 100 of arrays like this one with 50-100 products each, do you think this would be the most time-efficient way of doing it?  Even if it would save just a few seconds

Comment: @barnesc So you could make sure your config keywords were always lowercase so you don't need to keep `toLowerCase()`ing and I guess for more extreme optimization you could do some stuff like changing `.includes(str)` to  `.indexOf(str) !== -1`  — but you would need *tens of millions* of arrays to even measure the differences. There's no need for extreme optimization here.

Comment: i'll just make sure to keep my keywords all lowercase then, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `filter` and `some`

```
let filtered = products
    .filter(product => 
        product.title.split(' ')
            .some(s => config.keywords.includes(s.toLowerCase())))
```

```js
const config = {
  "keywords": [
    "vans",
    "nike"
  ]
}
let products = [{
    product_id: 'adidas-training-shoes',
    title: 'Adidas Training Shoes',
    description: 'description',
    brand: 'brand',
    variants: [
      [Object],
      [Object]
    ],
    thumbnail_url: 'url'
  },
  {
    product_id: 'nike-running-shoes',
    title: 'Nike Running Shoes',
    description: 'description',
    brand: 'brand',
    variants: [
      [Object],
      [Object],
      [Object],
      [Object]
    ],
    thumbnail_url: 'url'
  },
  {
    product_id: 'vans-sneakers',
    title: 'Vans Sneakers',
    description: 'description',
    brand: 'brand',
    variants: [
      [Object],
      [Object],
      [Object]
    ],
    thumbnail_url: 'url'
  }
]

let filtered = products.filter(product => product.title.split(' ').some(s => config.keywords.includes(s.toLowerCase())))

console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let keywords = ["vans", "nike" ]

let filteredObject = product.filter(obj => {
   return keywords.some((val => {
       return obj.title.toLowerCase().includes(val); 
   })
})
```

Comment: Correction: let filteredObject = product.filter(obj => {
   return keywords.some(val => {
       return obj.title.toLowerCase().includes(val); 
   })
})

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```js
var filtered = products.filter(function(item){
   var flag = false;
   config.keywords.forEach(function(word){
      var result = item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(word);
      if (result != -1){
         flag = true;
      }
   });
   return flag;
});
```